# VB.Net: Use different date format from Excel sheet while importing

Tags: vb.net

From an Excel sheet I import to MSAccess database. When I read the date column from the Excel sheet, want to convert it to known date format.
I get two Excel formats, one with dd-mm-yyyy format and another with mm/dd/yyyy.

When I import Excel sheet with date 9/14/2015, I get an error message "string was not recoganized as valid date time".

timesheetDate = xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, Column).value
tempDate = Convert.ToDateTime(timesheetDate)

How to convert to two different formats of date to one format?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I using the two properties: "ToOADate" and "FromOADate" when converting or moving data with no problems.
For sample: if you want to read a date from Excel to your form
Convert cell of date in Excel to number.
In form: convert the number to a date.May this short script help you:

```
Dim DateAsNumber As Integer
DateAsNumber = Int(Now.ToOADate)
MsgBox(DateAsNumber) 'if now is 13-Apr-2016 will you get 42473
Dim MyDate As Date
MyDate = DateTime.FromOADate(DateAsNumber)
MsgBox(MyDate) 'this will convert 42473 to 13/4/2016 or 4/13/2016 depending on your system date format.
```